# How is VIP swapping + CNAMEs better than IP swapping + A records?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment

I'm in the middle of updating my DNS setup to use all CNAMEs instead of A records, because I need support for VIP swaps between Staging and Production.  I can't use A records for this because that puts a dependency on a VIP that will be changing for each deployment.

Previously, I was using A records because of wildcard AND base domain support - I could map mydomain.com and all subdomains to the VIP and everything just worked.

CNAMEs make this a bit more complicated, but not impossible.

My question(s) is - with VIP swaps, the site url (mysite.cloudapp.net) needs to change from pointing to the original VIP, to the new VIP, right?  If so, doesn't DNS need to propagate anyways?  What happens to all of the cached DNS records that have `mysite.cloudapp.net` pointing to the original VIP?  Isn't there still a delayed propagation, and a chance that requests will get forwarded to the old VIP while this propagation occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VIP swap is an internal change to Azure's routers/load balancers, not an external DNS change. They're just routing traffic to go from one internal [set of] server[s] to another instead. Therefore the DNS info for mysite.cloudapp.net doesn't change at all. Therefore the change for people accessing via the IP bound to mysite.cloudapp.net (and CNAME'd by you) will see the change as soon as the VIP swap is complete.

Comment: > Therefore the DNS info for mysite.cloudapp.net doesn't change at all  -  

When I do a dns lookup for A records against my site.cloudapps.net, I see an IP address that corresponds to my VIP.  When I do a VIP swap, this won't change?  If it won't, can I just use A records then, and depend on that IP always being there as long as my service is hosted?

Comment: If you ever recreate your Azure application the VIP itself could change, thus resulting in a DNS record update, and that's why it's best to just use CNAMES.

Comment: Assuming I don't plan on ever recreating (it's up for good) - can I perform VIP swaps while using A records?  I don't like using CNAMEs because of problems like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863012/site-url-not-working-with-windows-azure-cloud-service)

Comment: Sorry for badgering but - if my VIP is currently whatever the DNS lookup returns, and I do a VIP swap, and then kill my staging environment, I've read that the original VIP becomes recycled / removed.  I'm very confused about how this change won't get propagated to future DNS lookups.

Comment: The IP should not change unless you were to delete both production and staging. Read this doc here (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/), specifically: "The IP address gets created the first time you deploy to an empty slot (either production or staging) in the hosted service and is retained by the slot until you delete the deployment from that slot."

Comment: I'm almost understanding.  New question here for some additional concerns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864695/vip-swaps-and-persistence-when-exactly-do-vips-get-recycled